# Bootstrap 4 - using Flexbox with responsive columns

Tags: responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a row with buttons positioned at the beginning of the row and at the end. Here are two images. First when the Browser is maximized:
[image]

The second is after I resized the Browser:

[image]

For that I am implementing the following code:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
   <div class="mr-auto p-2">Flex item 1</div>
   <div class="p-2">Flex item 2</div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1cv8f4bb/)

Just to learn how to use Flexbox with B4. The code does position items correctly, but when I resize it the columns dont stack up.

Any idea how to make it fully responsive?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `flex-row` and `flex-column` classes can also be used responsively. You could use `flex-sm-row` to keep the row horizontal on sm and up, then `flex-column` to stack vertically on `xs` screen widths...

```
<div class="d-flex flex-sm-row flex-column">
  <div class="mr-auto p-2">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item 2</div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/G3Z6OLCBtF

Answer (score 0):

Add flex-wrap after d-flex. It will make your screen responsive.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-end">
   <div class="mr-auto p-2">Flex item 1</div>
   <div class="p-2">Flex item 2</div>
</div>
```